# GRE Quantitative Reasoning Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Please may I get a second opinion to the solution of this question:
Given: $x < 1$ and $x \neq 0$ compare: $x^2 + 1$ with $x^3 + 1$

Answer Options
(1) Is one expression greater than the other
(2) Are the two equal
(3) Or is more information needed.

It is NOT an assignment and I need to understand the solution offered by the test makers. My reasoning and answer are different.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, if you want a *second* opinion, it might be useful to provide us with a first one.

Comment: I was trying not to sway the answers in any particular direction

Comment: You may assume that we can get to a good answer irrespective of what you say, as long as the question is fine. However, if your point in asking the question is to figure out what's possibly incorrect in your line of reasoning, it is most useful to provide us with your reasoning. Else you'll end up with another solution, possibly identical to the one in your manual, and learn nothing new.

Comment: Ok...I plugged in values. The two I used were x = 0.5 and x = -2, leading me to conclude more information was needed. However, the solution in the book reduced both sides of x^2 + 1 ? x^3 + 1 to x ? x^2, ending with x^2 + 1 > x^3 + 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $0 < x < 1$ then $0 < x^3 < x^2 < 1$, so $x^3+1 < x^2+1$; and if $x < 0$ then $x^2 > 0$, so that $x^2 + 1 > 1$, but $x^3 < 0$, so that $x^3+1 < 1 < x^2+1$.

In any case, we have $x^3+1 < x^2+1$.

Comment: I noticed. Thanks. I see my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Solution with
no separate cases:

$(x^3+1)-(x^2+1)
=x^3-x^2
=x^2(x-1)
< 0
$
since
$x^2 > 0$
and $x-1 < 0$.